# Tcl Podcast out there?

Tags: tcl, podcast

Is there any Tcl podcasts (in English)? It's not hard to find about Ruby, Python, Java, etc, but what about Tcl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of. There are some blogs, but not much else. For a list of bloggers, point your web browser to wiki.tcl.tk/12061